# Working Shopify GraphQL API for automating photo uploads, but I keep running into a string formatting error

Tags: python, automation, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I've tried adjusting the formatting to work but I keep running into the same error regardless of the changes. I'm new to GraphQL and Shopify so I'm a little stumped.

The goal I'm trying to achieve is automating uploading some where around 2000 photos to a shopify store, and doing so based on a SKU/ProductID combo to prevent the photos from going to the wrong item. I already have a fairly functional version of this using REST API instead but I wanted to make things more efficient and faster by using GraphQL.

```
import os
import re
import time
import base64
import logging
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

from shopify_config import SHOPIFY_STORE_URL, API_KEY, PASSWORD, API_VERSION

class ShopifyConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = f"{SHOPIFY_STORE_URL}/admin/api/{API_VERSION}/graphql.json"
        self.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token': PASSWORD
        }
        self.session = self._setup_session()

    def _setup_session(self):
        """Sets up a session with retry capabilities."""
        session = requests.Session()
        retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[502, 503, 504])
        session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
        return session

    def make_request(self, query):
        """Makes a GraphQL request to the Shopify API."""
        return self.session.post(self.base_url, headers=self.headers, json={'query': query})

##Used to paginate through shopify inventory and handle rate limits
class ShopifyPaginator:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    def _handle_rate_limits(self, response):
        """Handle rate limits based on the response headers."""
        # Extract the rate limit headers
        query_cost = int(response.headers.get('X-Shopify-Storefront-Graphql-Call-Cost', 0))
        remaining_cost = int(response.headers.get('X-Shopify-Storefront-Graphql-Remaining-Cost', 1000))

        # Calculate the time to sleep based on the query cost and remaining bucket size
        if remaining_cost < query_cost:
            sleep_time = (query_cost - remaining_cost) / 50  # 50 points refill per second
            print("---------------------------------------------------------")
            print(f"Rate limit usage high, sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds")
            print("---------------------------------------------------------")
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

    def get_all_items(self, query, item_key):
        """Fetch all items from a paginated Shopify GraphQL endpoint."""
        items = []
        cursor = None

        while True:
            # Format the query with the cursor if it exists
            formatted_query = query.format(cursor=f'"{cursor}"' if cursor else 'null')
            response = self.connection.make_request(formatted_query)
            self._handle_rate_limits(response)  # Handle rate limits

            data = response.json()
            items.extend(data.get('data', {}).get(item_key, {}).get('edges', []))

            # Check for pagination
            if items and 'cursor' in items[-1]:
                cursor = items[-1]['cursor']
            else:
                break

        return items
    
    
##Filters for shopify
class ShopifyProductFilter:
    def __init__(self, paginator, namespace, key):
        self.paginator = paginator
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.key = key 

    def get_ProductIDandSKUsWithPhotoFalse(self):
        """Fetch a list of product IDs and their respective SKUs where the metafield value is FALSE."""
        
        query = """
        {{
            products(first: 250, after: {cursor}) {{
                edges {{
                    cursor
                    node {{
                        id
                        variants(first: 5) {{
                            edges {{
                                node {{
                                    sku
                                }}
                            }}
                        }}
                        metafields(first: 5, namespace: "{namespace}", key: "{key}") {{
                            edges {{
                                node {{
                                    value
                                }}
                            }}
                        }}
                    }}
                }}
            }}
        }}
        """


        
        formatted_query = query.format(namespace=self.namespace, key=self.key, cursor="{cursor}")
        
        products = self.paginator.get_all_items(formatted_query, 'products')
        
        SKUandProductID = []
        
        for product in products:
            if any(metafield['node']['value'] == 'FALSE' for metafield in product['node']['metafields']['edges']):
                product_id = product['node']['id']
                for variant in product['node']['variants']['edges']:
                    sku = variant['node']['sku']
                    SKUandProductID.append({'product_id': product_id, 'sku': sku})
        return SKUandProductID



class ShopifyPhotoUploader:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.missing_photos = []
        self.successfully_uploaded = []

    def select_folder(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
        return folder_selected

    def upload_images_from_folder(self, folder_path, SKUandProductID):
        # Iterate through files in the folder and subfolders
        for root, _, files in os.walk(folder_path):
            for file in files:
                # Check if the file matches the naming scheme "GCE#20001_1.jpg"
                match = re.match(r'GCE#(\d+)_(\d+)\.jpg', file)
                if match:
                    sku, position = match.groups()
                    product_id = next((item['product_id'] for item in SKUandProductID if item['sku'] == sku), None)
                    if product_id:
                        full_image_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                        if self.upload_image(product_id, full_image_path, int(position), sku):
                            self.successfully_uploaded.append({'product_id': product_id, 'sku': sku})
                    else:
                        self.missing_photos.append(sku)

        # Create a log file for SKUs without photos
        if self.missing_photos:
            with open('missing_photos.log', 'w') as log_file:
                log_file.write("\n".join(self.missing_photos))

        # Update metafields for successfully uploaded images
        for item in self.successfully_uploaded:
            self.update_metafield(item['product_id'], "custom", "photo_shoot_", "True")

    def upload_image(self, product_id, image_path, position, sku):
        """Upload an image to Shopify using GraphQL."""
        # Encode the image to base64
        with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
            encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
        
        # GraphQL mutation for uploading the image
        mutation = """
        mutation productImageCreate($productId: ID!, $image: ImageInput!) {
            productImageCreate(productId: $productId, image: $image) {
                image {
                    id
                    src
                }
                userErrors {
                    field
                    message
                }
            }
        }
        """


        # Variables for the mutation
        variables = {
            "productId": product_id,
            "image": {
                "attachment": encoded_image,
                "filename": f"{sku}_{position}.jpg",
                "position": position
            }
        }

        # Send the mutation to Shopify
        response = self.connection.make_request(mutation, variables)
        data = response.json()

        # Check for errors
        user_errors = data.get('data', {}).get('productImageCreate', {}).get('userErrors', [])
        if user_errors:
            for error in user_errors:
                field = error.get('field', 'Unknown field')
                message = error.get('message', 'Unknown error')
                print(f"Error uploading image for SKU {sku} at position {position}: {field} - {message}")
            return False
        else:
            image_id = data.get('data', {}).get('productImageCreate', {}).get('image', {}).get('id')
            image_src = data.get('data', {}).get('productImageCreate', {}).get('image', {}).get('src')
            print(f"Successfully uploaded image for SKU {sku} at position {position}. Image ID: {image_id}, Image URL: {image_src}")
            return True

    def update_metafield(self, product_id, namespace, key, value):
        """Update a product's metafield using GraphQL."""
        mutation = """
        mutation productUpdate($input: ProductInput!) {
            productUpdate(input: $input) {
                product {
                    id
                }
                userErrors {
                    field
                    message
                }
            }
        }
        """

        # Variables for the mutation
        variables = {
            "input": {
                "id": product_id,
                "metafields": [{
                    "namespace": namespace,
                    "key": key,
                    "value": value,
                    "valueType": "STRING"
                }]
            }
        }

        # Send the mutation to Shopify
        response = self.connection.make_request(mutation, variables)
        data = response.json()

        # Check for errors
        user_errors = data.get('data', {}).get('productUpdate', {}).get('userErrors', [])
        if user_errors:
            for error in user_errors:
                field = error.get('field', 'Unknown field')
                message = error.get('message', 'Unknown error')
                print(f"Error updating metafield for product {product_id}: {field} - {message}")
        else:
            print(f"Successfully updated metafield for product {product_id}.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    NAMESPACE = 'custom'
    KEY = 'photo_shoot_'
    
    connection = ShopifyConnection()
    paginator = ShopifyPaginator(connection)
    
    filter = ShopifyProductFilter(paginator, NAMESPACE, KEY)
    SKUandProductID = filter.get_ProductIDandSKUsWithPhotoFalse()
    
    uploader = ShopifyPhotoUploader(connection)
    
    folder_path = uploader.select_folder()
    if not folder_path:
        print("No folder selected. Exiting")
        exit()
        
    uploader.upload_images_from_folder(folder_path, SKUandProductID)
    
    print("Image upload process complete!")
```

Here is the error

```
  File "c:\Users\**\Desktop\ShopifyAutomation\RefactoredCode\uploadTool.py", line 272, in <module>
    SKUandProductID = filter.get_ProductIDandSKUsWithPhotoFalse()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\**\Desktop\ShopifyAutomation\RefactoredCode\uploadTool.py", line 117, in get_ProductIDandSKUsWithPhotoFalse
    products = self.paginator.get_all_items(formatted_query, 'products')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\**\Desktop\ShopifyAutomation\RefactoredCode\uploadTool.py", line 60, in get_all_items
    formatted_query = query.format(cursor=f'"{cursor}"' if cursor else 'null')
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: '\n            products(first'
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, just incase anyone runs into issues with headers like I did just double check your "/"s and ""s. I had an extra "/" in my base url string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).